# Probability to ever go broke using exponential martingale

Tags: calculus, probability

Here the problem I want to solve (Extracted form "Probability: Theory and Examples 5th edition" Durrett, exercise 4.8.10) :

"Consider a favorable game in which the payoffs are 1, -1, or 2 with probability 1/3 each. Use the result of the previous problem  to compute the probability we ever go broke when we start with $\$i$, i.e our winnings reach $0$)"

Here the "previous problem":

Continuing with the set-up of the previous problem, suppose $\xi_i$ are integer valued with $P(\xi_i < -1) = 0$, $P(\xi_i = -1) > 0 $ and $\mathbb{E}\xi_i > 0 $. Let $ T_a = \inf\{n: S_n = a\}$ with $a<0$. Use the martingale $X_n = \exp{\theta_o S_n}$ to conclude that $P(T_a< \infty) = \exp{-\theta_o a}$.

Here the "set-up of the previous problem":
Let $S_n = \xi_1 + \cdots + \xi_n$ be a random and suppose that $\phi(\theta_o) = \mathbb{E}\exp{\theta_o \xi_1} = 1$ for some $\theta_o <0$ and $\xi_i$ is not constant.

I totally understand that to solve the first problem we just have to compute $P(T_a< \infty)$ with $a=-i$. However here I am not sure if Durrett means $i$ a complex number or not (what does it mean a complex wealth ?). Anyway complex or not to obtain $P(T_{-i}< \infty) = \exp{\theta_o i}$ we still need to compute $\theta_0$ and this is where I am lost I can't find a way to solve :

$1 = \mathbb{E}\exp{\theta_o \xi_1} = \frac{\exp{-\theta_o} + \exp{\theta_o} + \exp{2\theta_o}}{3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $i$ I think is a real number not the complex $i$. To find $\theta_0$, let $x_0 = e^{\theta_0}$. You have $$x_0^3+x_0^2-3x_0+1=0$$ You can see that $1$ is solution for the above equation (but you don't look for $\theta_0 =0$). Using this fact you can factorize the equation by $x_0-1$ and you have $$(x_0-1)(x_0^2 +2x_0-1)=0$$ Now you solve the second degree equation and you have two solution $$\frac{-2+\sqrt 8}2=\sqrt 2 - 1,\, \frac{-2-\sqrt 8}2 = -(\sqrt 2 +1)$$ You can observe that the first solution is $<1$ then it is enough to take $\theta_0 = \ln (\sqrt 2- 1)$